# How to update viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, hierarchy, userdefaults, viewwillappear

I’ve put code in ViewWillAppear and I’ve tried ViewDidAppear but the app only updates when I close it and re-open it. Anyone have any idea on how to fix this? I’m using UserDefaults to update the app with. I’m new to swift and I’m using storyboard so could it have something to do with the hierarchy ? Any help on this would be really appreciated.

I am creating an app with a spinning wheel which updates with options put in a table view, ive added some pictures to help illustrate.
The table view updates fine but when I go back to the main screen nothing happens until I close the app and re-open it

I link my github in case you want to look at full code base.

https://github.com/jamesnjones/Just.Decide

[ImageOfTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ouP1.png)

[ImageOfWheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po4vv.png)

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you actually *want* to have happen.  What needs to update and when?

Comment: Added some more information, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

solved by including
spinningWheel.setNeedsDisplay()
spinningWheel.setNeedsLayout()
in view will appear